# Grails and pdf generation

Tags: pdf, grails, pdf-generation

any experiences creating pdfs programmatically in Grails using some of the numerous java libs available ? Snippets are welcomed !

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your contributions, I opted for iText.

Comment: Give Grails Rendering Plugin a try. For the most work it's way more productive than iText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opted for iText, worked just fine.

Answer (score 9):

[Grails Rendering Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rendering) is the best option out there.

You just do a GSP (HTML+CSS) and it simply give you a PDF! Simple and fast!

Best regards!

Comment: Except the fact it does not support `<img>`

Comment: I agree with this answe. Grails Rendering Plugin is the best option out there, and actually it does support images! I followed this tutorial: [how do I render gsp files in pdf](http://www.icodeya.com/2012/09/grails-how-do-i-render-gsp-files-in-pdf.html)

Comment: every thing is working fine for me except font. I want to add my own font using css. Its working fine on browser but when I download it as pdf it does not show font.

Comment: This is the best option! If you want to render an image in the pdf, it cannot be a link, you must use the byte array encoded as Base64 `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, ${icon.data.encodeBase64()}" />`. Font will not work! You can see the right font in the browser because it has the font imported in sources, but ones you dowload the PDF file, this has no sources attached to it.

Answer (score 5):

you can try the plugins [Dynamic Jasper](http://www.grails.org/plugin/dynamic-jasper) or the [jasper plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jasper). The Dynamic Jasper plugin generates reports of your domain-class pretty simple, allowing customization of the reports. The Jasper plugin has tags to manipulate reports. The links contains snippets and samples.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using any XSL-FO rendering library like Apache FOP.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used this but if your looking to generate a PDF version of your view instead of html look at [this](http://www.grails.org/plugin/pdf) plugin. If you want to convert existing HTML into PDF look at [this](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html) If you want to generate custom PDF documents that arn't closely based on your views or domain classes you can check out [IText](http://itextpdf.com/) for the ability to generate complex documents.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [Export plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/export) which - besides PDF - generates CSV, Excel, ODS (Open Document Spreadsheets), RTF and XML.

Comment: Would be nice to give an example of how to use exportService.export since its so poorly documented.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I add page header & footer in the generated pdf?